# SQL Sum stock changes for multiple types with one type < 0

Tags: sql, sum

I'm using an sql statement for total of stockmutations and there are different ways how the stock will mutate.

In the following SQL query you will see that i check for types 1,6 and 9 that the stock will change and sum the total.

But there is still 1 more type to be added and that is type 0 and the only stock to sum this up = when the stock is a negative number.

```
 select ART.Artcode, SUM(VRDMUT.VrdMutAantal)
from Kingsystem.tabVoorraadMutatie VRDMUT
inner join Kingsystem.tabArtikel ART
on  ART.ArtGid = VRDMUT.VrdMutArtGid
where VRDMUT.VrdMutDatum between dateadd(day, -7, date(now())) and date(now()) AND VRDMUT.VrdMutSoort IN (1,6,9) 
GROUP BY ART.Artcode
```

Does someone know what to do with the query to get the result i want?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using an ODBC connection not sure which DBMS it is using

Answer (score 0):

Just use ABS in the SUM expression `SUM(ABS(VRDMUT.VrdMutAantal))`

with `AND VRDMUT.VrdMutSoort IN (0,1,6,9)`

Comment: This is not what i'm searching for